# Can we add Primary key to broken table

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, primary-key

I've a these tables:

```
Emp_Tutor: Tutor table.
Emp_Tu_De :Tutor details table.
Emp_Tu_St: Tutor status table.
Emp_School: School table.
```

As we know a school has many tutors, and each tutor maybe work in one school or another one maybe two or three schools.
So tutor table I played it as a Broken table between school and tutor details>

Tutor status table we create it to insert a tutor teaching status like( Courses, classes, teaching hours, ects.)

So my Question:
Can I Add a Primary Key to Tutor table to makes relation  between (Tutor table and Tutor status table)?
Don't forgot a tutor table is a broken relationship.
[look at image attachment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNG7B.png)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Zohar Peld for correcting my post, I'm wrote it quickly, because my laptop battery was has little power.

Answer (score 0):

I find that trying to store things like *status* is usually a mistake. For example, employment "status" of "current", "former", "rehire" is usually better implemented as an employment table with start dates and end dates.

*Broken table* and *broken relationship* aren't normal English terms in database design. I'm not sure what you mean here.

PostgreSQL code follows. SQL Server would use datetime data type in place of standard SQL's timestamp data type. There are probably other small differences.

```
-- Nothing surprising here.
create table schools (
  school_id integer primary key,
  school_name varchar(20) not null unique
  -- other columns go here
);

-- Nothing surprising here.
create table tutors (
  tutor_id integer primary key,
  tutor_name varchar(20) not null
  -- other columns go here
);

-- Nothing surprising here.
create table tutor_details (
  tutor_id integer primary key references tutors (tutor_id),
  tutor_phone varchar(15) 
  -- other columns go here
);

-- Predicate: School <school_id> employed <tutor_id> 
-- starting on <start_date> and ending on <end_date>.
-- Allows multiple periods of employment.
create table school_tutors (
  school_id integer not null references schools (school_id),
  tutor_id integer not null references tutors (tutor_id),
  start_date date not null default current_date,
  end_date date not null default '9999-12-31',
  -- You can make a good, practical argument for including end_date
  -- in the primary key, but that's a different issue.
  primary key (school_id, tutor_id, start_date)
);


-- Only makes sense in the context of employment, so a composite
-- foreign key references school_tutors. In production, I'd try
-- to use more check constraints on the timestamps.
create table tutor_office_hours (
  school_id integer not null,
  tutor_id integer not null,
  start_date date not null,
  foreign key (school_id, tutor_id, start_date) 
    references school_tutors (school_id, tutor_id, start_date),
  office_hours_start_time timestamp not null,
  office_hours_end_time timestamp not null
    check (office_hours_end_time > office_hours_start_time),
  primary key (school_id, tutor_id, office_hours_start_time)
);
```